# Efficient implementation of std::vector-like container's constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector, implementation

`std::vector` has a constructor which is in the form of

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Then, how do you implement this constructor if the iterator is not a random-access one?
I came up with two candidates...

1. In a loop, call `push_back(*first)`(assume push_back is already implemented) while first != last .
2. Count the number of elements by `std::distance(first, last)`,
   then allocate enough memory, then copy construct all the elements.

Which is better?, or do you have any other ideas?

Addition:
My bad, if the iterator is an input_iterator, idea 2 is not even possible.

Comment: If you pass a forward iterator it uses distance+reserve. otherwise it doesnt.

Comment: @MooingDuck, thanks. But will you explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The usual implementation is something like

```
private:
template<class input_iterator>
std::size_t size_if_possible(input_iterator first, input_iterator last, std::input_iterator_tag) {
}
template<class input_iterator>
std::size_t size_if_possible(input_iterator first, input_iterator last, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
    return std::distance(first, last);
}

public:
template<class input_iterator>
vector(input_iterator first, input_iterator last) {
    reserve(size_if_possible(first, last, std::iterator_traits<input_iterator>::tag{}));
    while (first != last) {
        emplace_back(*first);
        first++;
    }
}
```

This allows it to reserve if you pass in a forward iterator, and effectively skip the reserve if you pass in a single pass input iterator, giving you the best of both worlds.

Comment: thanks, But, the problem is, such implementation iterates over the range **twice** if the iterator is a forward-iterator but not a random-access iterator. And such a iterator is often quite slow to iterate. So, essentially, this question is asking the cost of redundant and slow iteration vs potential reallocations. Without  the consideration, answers are meaning less.